# netty terminate tls using kubernetes certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, netty

I am trying to terminate TLS in a netty webserver in a Kubernetes cluster.

I am using [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/) to manage my website's certificates

Here is the result of
`kubernetes get secret websitesslcert-staging -o yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  tls.crt: REDACTED=
  tls.key: REDACTED=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/alt-names: mysite.com
    cert-manager.io/certificate-name: websitesslcert-staging
    cert-manager.io/common-name: mysite.com
    cert-manager.io/ip-sans: ""
    cert-manager.io/issuer-group: cert-manager.io
    cert-manager.io/issuer-kind: ClusterIssuer
    cert-manager.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-staging
    cert-manager.io/uri-sans: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-17T00:00:00Z"
  name: websitesslcert-staging
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "123456"
  uid: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
type: kubernetes.io/tls
```

The format of the kubernetes.io/tls is described [in the Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets).

> The public/private key pair must exist beforehand. The public key
> certificate for --cert must be .PEM encoded (Base64-encoded DER
> format), and match the given private key for --key. The private key
> must be in what is commonly called PEM private key format,
> unencrypted. In both cases, the initial and the last lines from PEM
> (for example, --------BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -------END
> CERTIFICATE---- for a certificate) are not included.

I have a Java (Netty) application that has to [terminate TLS](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslContext.html).
Locally I can copy the secrets ("tls.crt" and "tls.key") and write them to files, however I am not able to use them in my local server Netty 4 to accept TLS connections.

```
 ChannelPipeline p = channel.pipeline();
 SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(tlsKeyFile, tlsCertFile).build();
 p.addLast("ssl", sslCtx.newHandler(channel.alloc()));
```

results in an error:

```
Execution error (CertificateException) at io.netty.handler.ssl.PemReader/readCertificates (PemReader.java:98).
found no certificates in input stream
```

Adding  --------BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -------END CERTIFICATE----  to the files results in

```
Execution error (CertificateParsingException) at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl/parse (X509CertImpl.java:1826).
signed overrun, bytes = 919
```

How should I approach this, to read my certificate from Netty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the certificates are base64-encode in the yaml output. `base64 --decode` shows the files contents.